# Avoid blocking with state variable copies?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'd like some wisdom regarding a recent multithreading idea of mine. Here goes:

Suppose I have the following (pseudo) class whose `run()` method is chugging away forever on some thread. Other threads will at random times change the state of the `Foo` instance using `setState()`. The work that `run()` is doing only involves reading the state variables, no writing, and the state must not change during one execution of the while statement (example: drawing on a bitmap).

In this case, having 2 copies of the state variables seems to prevent a lot of potential blocking (since if I only had one copy of shared state variables, I would have to synchronize everything in the while loop (using `stateLock`) and outside threads may not get the chance to change the state). Questions after the code break.

```
class Foo {
  Object stateLock = new Object();

  private float my1, my2, my3;
  private float sh1, sh2, sh3;  // sh stands for shared

  public void setState(...) {
    synchronized (stateLock) {
      // modify sh1, sh2, or sh3 here
    }
  }

  private void updateState() {
    synchronized (stateLock) {
      // set my1=sh1, my2=sh2, my3=sh3
    }
  }

  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      updateState();
      // then do tons of stuff that uses my1,my2,my3 over and over...
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Any holes in this logic? Is there a "standardized" or smarter way of doing this? What if there are tons of state variables? Worse, what if state variables are custom objects that don't copy easily (e.g. in java where variables of custom objects are references)?

By the way, this comes from my current work with a SurfaceView in Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep all the variables in sync and to avoid synchronization, you can put the variables inside an immutable object and update it as a whole. When reading the state, keep hold of one such state object as local variable, and you will be guaranteed that nobody else updates it while you are reading it.

Here is some sample code (not tested etc.). If the old values are not read in `setState` or it is accessed only from one thread, then a volatile field would be enough. But in the general case (multiple threads calling setState and the new state depends on the value of the old state), using AtomicReference makes sure that the no updates will be missed.

```
class Foo {
    private final AtomicReference<State> state = new AtomicReference<State>(new State(0, 0, 0));

    private void setState(float x1, float x2, float x3) {
        State current;
        State updated;
        do {
            current = state.get();
            // modify the values
            float sh1 = current.sh1 + x1;
            float sh2 = current.sh2 + x2;
            float sh3 = current.sh3 + x3;
            updated = new State(sh1, sh2, sh3);
        } while (!state.compareAndSet(current, updated));
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            State snapshot = state.get();
            // then do tons of stuff that uses sh1, sh2, sh3 over and over...
        }
    }

    private class State {
        public final float sh1, sh2, sh3;

        State(float sh1, float sh2, float sh3) {
            this.sh1 = sh1;
            this.sh2 = sh2;
            this.sh3 = sh3;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is sample code for the special case that updating the state does not depend on the old values of the state:

```
class Foo {
    private volatile State state = new State(0, 0, 0);

    private void setState(float sh1, float sh2, float sh3) {
        state = new State(sh1, sh2, sh3);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            State snapshot = state;
            // then do tons of stuff that uses sh1, sh2, sh3 over and over...
        }
    }

    private class State {
        public final float sh1, sh2, sh3;

        State(float sh1, float sh2, float sh3) {
            this.sh1 = sh1;
            this.sh2 = sh2;
            this.sh3 = sh3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice way of packaging this process (and without any explicit synchronization---bonus!). Thanks! (I happened to read the chapter on this in Java Concurrency in Practice just after your post.)

Comment: I haven't read "Java Concurrency in Practice", but probably I've collected the same information from a hundred other places. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler way of fixing this is:

```
private volatile float sh1, sh2, sh3;  // note "volatile"
```

In the java memory model, threads are allowed to cache values from other threads. 
The `volatile` keyword means that all threads *must* use the same variable value (ie all reference the same memory location of the variable). When used with primitives, it means you don't need synchronization (although with 64-bit primitives, of which float is **not** one, you *may* not need synchronization, depending on your JVM being 32- or 64-bit)

You may want to watch partial/inconsistent updates - where *some* of the `sh` variables are updated when another thread reads them. You may want to synchronize the updates to maintain consistent state by making your updates to multiple sh variables "atomic".

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this helps. Removing my1,my2,my3 in favor of shared volatile vars goes against the requirement that (local) state must not change during an iteration of the while loop. While read/writes are guaranteed not to interlace using volatile, it doesn't mean the state variables can't be changed by another thread part way through a while iteration. Esko's got a good solution that happens to come straight from Java Concurrency in Practice.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe you didn't mean to remove my1,my2,my3. In this case, however, making sh1,sh2,sh3 volatile is redundant, since `stateLock` "atomizes" state setting and getting.